# How can I remove the current and next instance in a dataframe (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have this dataframe, df. It's structured like this:

```
index     date    animal  park_visits
0         Jan      cat        1
1         Jan      dog        2
2         Feb      cat        1
3         Feb      dog        1
4         Feb      pig        4
5         March    cat        3
6         March    dog        2
7         March    pig        3
8         April    cat        2
```

How can I create a new dataframe such that, if in the current month an animal has less than a single park visits a month, to exclude that row as well as the next month's row?

For example, at index 0, the cat had only one park visit in January, so then I would exclude entries at index 0, and 2. Additionally, since the cat visited the park in February one time, I would also exclude the entry at index 5 when the cat visited the park 3 times in March. But since the cat attended the park 3 times in March, I would include the entry for April.

As a result, the ending, sample dataframe I would ultimately want is going to look something like this:

```
index    date    animal    park_visits
  0       Jan     dog          2
  1       Feb     pig          4
  2       March   pig          3
  3       April   cat          2
```

Is there any way to do this efficiently without a loop? My best guess is to create a new dataframe that is where park_visits is = 1, and with that, try and remove the next instance the date and animal are the same. However, I'm not sure how to remove ONLY the next instance, not all instances (so I would need to keep the entry where the date is April, animal is cat, and park_visits is 2). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We want to identify those rows where `park_visits` were greater than one this month and the prior month.  We use shift to check the prior month

```
f = lambda x: (lambda y: y & y.shift().fillna(True))(x > 1)

df[df.groupby('animal').park_visits.transform(f)]

        date animal  park_visits
index                           
1        Jan    dog            2
4        Feb    pig            4
7      March    pig            3
8      April    cat            2
```